# Why to serialize model class

Tags: java, serialization

Many times I see a model class will implement `Serializable`, but is never serialized.

1. What is purpose here to implement `Serializable`?
2. If serialization is not used, what will I miss? Is there any effect in the way the code communicates?

```
public class Stock implements Serializable{

    private int stockId;
    private String stockCode;
    private String stockName;

    //Getter and setter
}
```

Comment: Depends on the context of your class; if you're running it in something (like a framework) that requires your class to be serializable, that's why.

Comment: Implementing serializable makes it so if someone did want do serialize stock at any point of using the object they can. If it's not implemented no one will ever be able to serialize it. Also as Dave said, if you using some like java beans you might have to have it serialized.

Comment: @Javant Thanx I think that make a point.

Comment: Model classes are data containers and data is most of the time expected to be transferred from one party to another. Serilizable just ensures that this data can be passed over a stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is purpose here to implement Serializable?

Just a marker to indicate the possibility provided to clients of the class for serializing instances of them if they wish.

For example, if you instantiate Stock class and that you want to save Stock instances in a file, you can do it thanks to this marker. APIs (for example  Jaxb or Java native serialization mechanism) rely generally on the implementation of this interface to serialize class.

> If serialization is not used, what will I miss? Is there any effect in
>   the way the code communicates?

It's is not used, you have zero overhead or transformation in the communication of the instance since it is a marker interface. Only, when the serialization occurs, the communication of the instance changes.

Answer (score 0):

`Serializable` is just a marker interface without overhead*.
If you want class `A` to `implement serializable` and class `A` contains field with type `Stock`, `Stock` should also implement serializable.

May be there will be no direct `Stock` class instance serializations. But it will be serialized via class `A` instance.

Also implementing is necessary if you want `Stock` instance to become an argument of

```
type foo(? extends Serializable param)
```